# What does it exactly mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I live in Russia, but I applied for a job in Germany. At the begining of a recruitment process, they sent me an email with the following content :

"Wait for an email from our vendor X with instructions for submitting your background check form (only live for Germany, UK, France)."

As I applied to Germany, but I don't live there - should I submit this form or not ?

I don't really understand "live for" used in this context

Comment: This is a bit confusing, "live for" is ambiguous without further context (and may be incorrect grammatically). What is "check form"?  Could you give more context.

Comment: Yes, this company cooperate with another company which does background checking etc. That's why they ask to submit a form with relevant information

Comment: Maybe it's (only for those who live in)?

Comment: Is it possible for you to supply at least the complete sentence it appears in?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: It's probably the adjective pronounced /laɪv/ (in one of the meanings where it can function as a predicative complement), not the verb pronounced /lɪv/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the meanings of the adjective "live" is *actually being performed at the time of hearing or viewing*. *Only live for Germany, UK, France* means that  submissions made from other locations won't be accepted. *Live* here is synonymous to *existing at the present moment* (*for* the countries on the list).